# Rails 6 + Bootstrap - Link_to logout throws an error but button_to works fine. Why is it so?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bootstrap-5, ruby-on-rails-6.1

On adding Bootstrap 5 to my Rails 6 app, logout link which worked fine previously throws an error
<%= link_to "Log Out", destroy_user_session_path, :method => :delete %>  AbstractController::ActionNotFound (The action 'show' could not be found for UsersController)
I could fix this by replacing link_to with button_to. But why does link_to throw an error?

Answer (score 1):

You should use `link_to` only when simply redirecting user to a different page with show or index methods. Here you want to use `button_to` because it creates a custom form that carries additional data as you're manipulating with the database. You should use it with methods like update delete and create.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're missing `jquery_ujs` in your project. You can install it with a gem or through yarn, depending on what you like to use.

[Here](https://www.viget.com/articles/delete-in-rails-without-jquery-and-ujs/) you will find some more info on what `jquery_ujs` is and how it works.